# Add custom fields in a serializer based from instance criteria

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created a `Django 1.10` app with `Rest-Framework`, I have trouble making any custom field that will yield the date range of a date field in `M2MField`, i will explain my problem with my code.

```
class FoodConsumption(models.Model):
    '''
        An item consume by animal.
    '''

    animal = models.ForeignKey(
        Animal, related_name='animal_food_consumptions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    food = models.ForeignKey(
        Food, related_name='food_consumptions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date = models.DateField()


class FoodConsumptionTransaction(models.Model):
    herd = models.ForeignKey(
        Herd, related_name="food_consumption_transactions", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    food_consumptions = models.ManyToManyField(FoodConsumption)
```

And here is my serializer to display the `FoodConsumptionTransaction` data.

```
class FoodConsumptionTransactionListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FoodConsumptionTransaction
        fields = ['id', 'herd', 'food_consumptions']
```

Create a couple of `FoodConsumption`:

```
from dateutil import parser

fc1 = FoodConsumption.objects.create(
    animal=animal_obj_1, 
    food=food_obj_1,
    date=parser.parse('2017-04-06').date() // min date
)

fc2 = FoodConsumption.objects.create(
    animal=animal_obj_2, 
    food=food_obj_2,
    date=parser.parse('2017-04-08').date() 
)

fc3 = FoodConsumption.objects.create(
    animal=animal_obj_3, 
    food=food_obj_2,
    date=parser.parse('2017-04-10').date() // max date
)

# add to the transaction

fc_trans = FoodConsumptionTransaction.objects.create(
    herd=herd_obj_1
)
fc_trans .food_consumptions.add(fc1, fc2, fc3)
```

Now when getting data of `FoodTransaction` by herd i get this list:

```
[
   {
       "id": 1,
       "herd": 1,
       "food_consumptions": [1, 2, 3], # pks of FoodComsumption
   }
]
```

But how can i create extra fields based from `food_consumptions` field , `food.date` *(min and max)*?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "herd": 1,
        "food_consumptions": [1, 2, 3], # pks of FoodComsumption
        "min_date": '2017-04-6',    # get the min date of food
        "max_date": '2017-04-10',   # get the max date of food
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want are [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

You can override the default result returned from the serializer's `to_representation()` function. And add `min_date` and `max_date` fields to the result produced.

Such as

```
class  FoodSerializer(serialiers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super(FoodSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)     
        result['min_date'] = min[each.date for each in instance.m2mfield.all()]
        result['max_date'] = max[each.date for each in instance.m2mfield.all()] 
        return result
```

Comment: hi there! thanks for your response, got an invalid syntax in for each loop

Comment: That was some simple logic, you can make your own to get `min` and `max` of dates.

Comment: i think this one help me a lot.. thanks for a good idea, i did learn something useful here

Comment: instead of doing `min/max [each.date for each in instance.m2mfield.all()]` i replace it with `instance.m2mfield.earliest('date').date` for min and `instance.m2mfield.latest('date').date` for max

Comment: nice workaround, thanks for info. I keep forgetting these utilities already in the django.